# Traverse the string array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const char *s[] = {"a", "b", "c", NULL};
    const char **p = s;
    while (*p != NULL) {
        printf("string = %s\n", *p);
        (*p)++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to traverse the string array and print the string util come up the NULL sentinal.
However it generate a terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)message.
Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: while (*p), and (*p)++ are certainly suspect.

Comment: maybe because you are explicitly putting a null value in your string at the end. a string array will automatically include a null, you dont have to define it. remove the null and use a length() method for your loop. that may help.

Comment: @aradhna a string array will automatically include a null, you dont have to define it,I can't agree with that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this line :

```
(*p)++
```

You will increment `p[0]`.

I guess this is not what you want.

Replace it by :

```
p++;
```

It should work fine ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
(*p)++;
```

Should just be:

```
p++;
```

Here's what you are doing:

```
p --> * --> "a"
|     ^ incrementing this
checking this for null
```

You're incrementing the wrong pointer.

Comment: OP _does_ check the correct value for not being `0`. The wrong increment is the only issue here.